# How to create a scrollbar in html

Tags: html, scrollbar

I already searched for this problem, I did not found, i already trying to learn from "How to ask" section : https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

In my Homepage i have 2 categories,, "Services" and "Works", when i want to add the thirst category the text inside will go down, without i can scroll to see the entire text

Image : http://www.youlikexxx.com/image/image/image.png

Comment: maybe try `overflow: auto;` in the css for that div?

Comment: Better show your code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can use CSS property `overflow: auto;` for div that contains text or you can use JQuery custom scrollbar plugin if you want any stylish scrollbar.
here is link:

http://manos.malihu.gr/tuts/jquery_custom_scrollbar.html

Comment: If you use `overflow: scroll` it will show scroll in both sides horizontal and vertical even if not needed but `overflow: auto;` will show scroll only where it needed.

Comment: WOW WOW WOW Thank you , this is the real answer :)

Answer (score 0):

```
.divname{ overflow:scroll; min-height:500px;}

in html page call the class
```

Answer (score 0):

Use

```
 overflow:scroll; height:200px;
```

instead oveflow:hidden;